# Hamiltonian operator and spin operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, hamiltonian

I've just started *Quantum mechanics*
by McIntyre and have understood the following about operators :

- Each observable has an operator
- Operators act on kets to produce another kets.
- Only eigenvalues of an operator are possible values of a measurement.

Now the author introduces the Hamiltonian operator $H$ and says

> The
> eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian are the allowed energies of the quantum system, and the eigenstates
> of $H$ are the energy eigenstates of the system.

I understood this.

Then the author discusses about a Spin 1/2 particle in a constant magnetic field along $z$ direction.

> The Hamiltonian operator represents the total energy of the system... So to begin, we consider the potential energy of a single magnetic dipole (e.g., in a silver atom) in a uniform magnetic field as the sole term in the Hamiltonian. Recalling that the magnetic dipole is given by
> $$
> \mu=g \frac{q}{2 m_{e}} \mathbf{S}
> $$
> the Hamiltonian is
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> H &=-\mu \cdot \mathbf{B} \\
> &=-g \frac{q}{2 m_{e}} \mathbf{S} \cdot \mathbf{B} \\
> &=\frac{e}{m_{e}} \mathbf{S} \cdot \mathbf{B}
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> $$
> \mathbf{B}=B_{0} \hat{\mathbf{z}}
> $$
> allows the Hamiltonian to be simplified to
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> H &=\frac{e B_{0}}{m_{e}} S_{z} \\
> &=\omega_{0} S_{z}
> \end{aligned}
> \tag 1$$
> where
> $$
> \omega_{0} \equiv \frac{e B_{0}}{m_{e}}
> $$
> The Hamiltonian is proportional to the $S_{z}$ operator.

- The way equation (1) was derived took $H$ to be energy and $S$ to be a vector therefore it isn't a operator relationship.
  Why then does the author say it is an operator relationship by saying that " The Hamiltonian is proportional to the $S_{z}$ operator" ?
- I understand that if a  particle having a magnetic moment $\mu$ is in a magnetic field $B$ then it has energy $E$ (a scalar) given as $E=-{\mu}. B$

Now in QM we have an operator relationship between the Hamiltonian (operator) and magnetic moment (operator) exactly in the same form as $H=-{\mu}.B$

Why is that so?

Based on what the author has written so far as I've mentioned in starting of this post I cannot understand this correspondence.

Answer (score 1):

Equation (1) is an operator relationship since, to derive that, you do the dot-product between $\vec{S}$ and $\vec{B}$, so you don't get a vector. So you have an expression of the operator $H$ in terms of another operator: $S_z$. In $\hat{z}$ direction because $\vec{B}=B_0\hat{z}$. So you can have your eingenstates and eingenvalues.

Comment: "*you do the dot-product between $\vec{S}$ and $\vec{B}$*"  aren't $\vec{S}$ and $\vec{B}$ vectors here?

Comment: @Kashmiri you can only perform a dot product between two vectors, resulting in a scalar.

Comment: @Mauricio, yes that's what I'm saying. They are vectors and not operators

Comment: @Kashmiri You can have vector operators, $\mathbf O= (O_x,O_y,O_z)$ where each component is an operator.

Comment: @Mauricio, you suggest   and $\mathbf S $ is a vector having components as operators ? What about $\mu$

Comment: @Kashmiri a constant times an operator is still and operator, $\mathbf S$ and $\mu$ are proportional times a constant. The best example of operator vector is the gradient $\nabla =(\partial_x,\partial_y,\partial_z)$ (which is proportional to the momentum operator).

Comment: @Mauricio, Thank you so much. One more request please, why is  $H=-\mu \cdot \mathbf{B}$?

Comment: @Kashmiri http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magpot.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133845/discussion-between-kashmiri-and-mauricio).